# Why my aab file is bigger than apk for an Android app?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

It's been awhile since Google has introduced aab file as a recommended way of distributing Android apps through their Play Store. I was hesitant to use it, because I'm concerned that Goggle can get dynamic linking wrong and the app won't work on some devices at which point I would not know how to help users. In general, my confidence in their ability to deliver anything new that doesn't crash is very slim lately.

However, Play Store is very persistent in showing warnings that I should really switch to aab. One of the advertised advantages is that the size and install time on the target devices will be smaller. After building aab and apk today I've noticed that aab is bigger than apk.

I've two questions about this for the people who have already switched to aab:

1. Did you experience any crashes or any other problems attributed to dynamic aab linking?
2. Is there any point of switching to aab given that its size even bigger than apk? Are there any advantages for users in doing that?

   8.3M Apr 18 14:48 mobile-release.apk

   9.1M Apr 18 14:49 mobile-release.aab

Update. Looks like AAB will be mandatory starting in August. Another interesting question in this regard would be how to test AAB for all possible target device configs to make sure that it won't crash the app.
[image]

Comment: "Is there any point of switching to aab given that its size even bigger than apk?" -- while the AAB itself might be bigger, an individual user only gets pieces of that AAB. The user does not get the entire AAB.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. What about problems with linking by Play that will create different executables for each device configuration? Is it error prone?

Comment: "Is it error prone?" -- that I cannot answer, sorry. I have [my own issues with App Bundles](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/09/23/uncomfortable-questions-app-signing.html) and do not use them. The only reason I know the AAB size issue was from doing research on the subject.

Comment: Thanks again. You can post the answer if you want and I'll accept, even though I consider it partial.